# creating a json output

Tags: php, json

I creating a json output and this is how it looks right now :

```
{"attributes":{"next":4189646},"images":{"0":{"id":"4188043","title":"Easter Island ....
```

but I want it to look like:

```
{"attributes":{"next":4197237},"images":[{"id":4198434,"title":"Good Morning" ...
```

how can I get rid of the `images` array IDs??

Comment: What is your initial set of data?  What object are you trying to json_encode?  Most likely, you need to change the array of images to a corresponding object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for an array to be encoded as `[...]` rather than `{"0":...}`, the array must be a "pure" indexed array.

This can easily be achieved by running it through [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array-values) first.

Comment: thanks , that is exactly what I wanted, waiting for 9 mins to accept your answer ;)